# jQuery mobile: Dynamically loading content (problems with textbox)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, dynamic-content

I just have a problem with jQuery mobile if i change dynamically the html content of a div. Here is a minimal code for my problem, after it there is a detailed description:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function loadContent(content) {
                $('div.content').html(content);
                $('div.content').trigger('create');
            }

            $(function() {
                //loadContent('<input type="text" />'); <-- doesnt work
                loadContent('<button>Button0</button>');
                $('#change').click(function() {
                    loadContent('<button>Button1</button>');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
      <div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" id="myPanel"> 
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        <p>You can close the panel by clicking outside the panel, pressing the Esc key or by swiping.</p>
      </div> 

      <div data-role="header">
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <button id="change">Change content</button>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer">
        <div class="select-language">
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

The page contains a div with the class `content`. The javascript-function `loadContent(content)` just loads the given argument as plain html into all div elements with the class `content`.

After the html-code is loaded the trigger `create` is executed. This is because the html-code should be displayed with the jQuery mobile style.

The code example loads in the beginning a button `Button0` and after you've clicked on `Change content` there will be a button `Button1` instead of `Button0`. This works fine.

But if the initial `loadContent`-call contains an `input` tag it won't work. The `input` element is still there after recalling `loadContent`.

To test this i added a commented line. (The first line in the initialize function).

I found out that this only happens if i add the trigger for `create`, but without the trigger the content looks ugly.

Has anyone an idea why the `input` element is still there after recalling `loadContent`?

Thank you,

Best regards
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$(function() {...` you should use the jQuery Mobile page events like `pagecreate`. Also instead of `.trigger("create")`, with version 1.4 you can use `.enhanceWithin()`:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page", function () {
    loadContent('<input type="text" />');
    //loadContent('<button>Button0</button>');
    $('#change').click(function () {
        loadContent('<button>Button1</button>');
    });
});

function loadContent(content) {
    $('div.content').html(content).enhanceWithin();
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/v5GD6/1/)**

In your posted source code you are adding the jQM library twice. Just add the minimized one (jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js) and leave out the uncompressed one.